# Select all rows from Time Series data for a given day (by timestamp)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe has timestamps index and a column of data for many days. I would like to retrieve the data of particular days.

```
raw_df = 
                            Temp
TIMESTAMP                       
2015-01-01 09:50:00-05:00  0.064
2015-01-01 09:51:00-05:00  0.236
2015-01-01 09:52:00-05:00  0.268
2015-01-01 09:53:00-05:00  0.072
2015-01-01 10:07:00-05:00  0.059
2015-01-02 10:08:00-05:00  0.189
2015-01-02 10:09:00-05:00  0.198
2015-01-02 10:10:00-05:00  0.258
2015-01-02 10:11:00-05:00  0.587
2015-01-03 10:12:00-05:00  0.780
2015-01-03 10:13:00-05:00  0.990
2015-01-03 10:14:00-05:00  1.022
2015-01-03 10:15:00-05:00  1.275
2015-01-04 10:16:00-05:00  1.256
2015-01-04 10:17:00-05:00  1.255
2015-01-04 10:18:00-05:00  1.254
2015-01-04 10:19:00-05:00  1.305
2015-01-04 10:20:00-05:00  1.347
2015-01-04 10:21:00-05:00  1.434
2015-01-05 10:22:00-05:00  1.397
```

I would like to extract the data on 2015-01-04 and my code is given below

```
i = 2015-01-04
raw_df['Temp'].loc[i]
```

But this gives an error

```
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

Comment: @VasuDeo.S My understanding is, `.loc` helps us to search in index. So I have used it. I want the data of that day so I have put `[Temp]`

Comment: You should have enclosed `2015-01-04` in quotes: `i = "2015-01-04"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a multitude of options but all of them will need to bridge the gap between the datetime index and the date string.

#### Boolean Indexing

```
# df[df.index.tz_localize(None).floor('D') == '2015-01-04']
df[df.index.floor('D') == '2015-01-04']
# Or,
df[df.index.normalize() == '2015-01-04']
```

Or, to select just "Temp", use `loc`:

```
df.loc[df.index.floor('D') == '2015-01-04', 'Temp']

TIMESTAMP
2015-01-04 10:16:00-05:00    1.256
2015-01-04 10:17:00-05:00    1.255
2015-01-04 10:18:00-05:00    1.254
2015-01-04 10:19:00-05:00    1.305
2015-01-04 10:20:00-05:00    1.347
2015-01-04 10:21:00-05:00    1.434
Name: Temp, dtype: float64
```

---

#### Slicing with `Index.get_loc`

```
# df.iloc[df.index.get_loc('2015-01-04')]
df.iloc[df.index.get_loc('2015-01-04'), df.columns.get_loc('Temp')]

TIMESTAMP
2015-01-04 10:16:00-05:00    1.256
2015-01-04 10:17:00-05:00    1.255
2015-01-04 10:18:00-05:00    1.254
2015-01-04 10:19:00-05:00    1.305
2015-01-04 10:20:00-05:00    1.347
2015-01-04 10:21:00-05:00    1.434
Name: Temp, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer worked for me. Thanks for letting me about the new function. `Index.get_loc`. This is something about extracting the required rows by calling their index positions but using `loc`. Because `loc` does not take index positions.

Comment: @cs95 as a side question, when you're confronted with questions in this format, how do you convert the table into a dataframe? in other words, I'm sure you don't write df=pd.DataFrame({.... 'and write the entire table here'.

Comment: @adhg [`pd.read_clipboard`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_clipboard.html) is your friend. For this specific problem, I copied the data in the OP and typed `df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=r'\s{2,}', index_col=[0], parse_dates=['TIMESTAMP'])` into a terminal.